# What is the maximum height a pendulum can reach?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, energy-conservation

I've been trying to solve this problem:

> The sphere of mass  of a pendulum of length  is initially held
> vertically. When a wind blows with a constant force 
> non-conservative, show that if the sphere starts moving from rest, the
> maximum height it reaches is
> $$
>   H=\begin{pmatrix}
>      2L\\
>   \hline
>     1+(\frac{mg}F)^2 \\
>   \end{pmatrix}
> $$

I don't understand why the non-conservative bit is important to mention, it is still on a conservative field, that being the gravitational field. I've been trying all kinds of things, seeing how would the given expression behave, plugin in numbers to the problem, trying to instead of wind blowing another force was acting, trying to do something with the conservation of energy assuming that the sphere would fall, tried to do something with vectorial calculus and still can't find a way to arrive to the solution. I'm not quite sure how to pose the problem. What physical concepts are relevant here?

So, what are the forces acting on the pendulum? Why does de pendulum reaches its highest point? By this I mean, what makes the pendulum stop at a certain point,that being his highest point. Does the force applied by the wind only affects it at the start of the movement? Pretty much like hitting a baseball, there is only few seconds of contact before the baseball starts moving?, is the concept of momentum any relevant to understand this problem?

Comment: Is the wind blowing in a constant direction? If so, seems like you could treat it as a conservative force regardless of what the problem says.

Comment: i don't know if the wind blows in a constant direction, the problem doesn't state anything else, but I might try to take it as a conservative force

Comment: The non-conservative part is not important to mention, and in fact it's not even true. Any constant force is conservative. That wording was probably put there by whoever wrote the question to lead you to a work-energy relation like $\Delta K + \Delta U_g = W_F$, reminding you that you have to consider the work done by $\vec{\mathbf{F}}$ and not just the change in gravitational potential energy.

Comment: How exactly would you apply the work-energy relation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is far simpler than the sophisticated methods you’ve been using. It’s one of those cases when it’s better to know less rather than more.

I’ll write $G$ instead of $mg$ because it makes thinking easier.

The resultant of $F$ horizontally and $G$ vertically down is a downward force at an angle $\theta$ to the vertical, where $$\tan\theta=\frac F G$$

So we can treat this as a normal pendulum with no wind whose “bottom dead centre” position is $\theta$ away from our vertical.

The given initial position of the pendulum is $\theta$ to one side of its bottom dead centre.

So since a pendulum always swings to the same height it started from, the other end of its swing will be $\theta$ to the other side of its bottom dead centre. That is, $2\theta$ away from our vertical.

Thus simple trigonometry gives the maximum height as $$(1-\cos 2\theta)L$$

After that, it’s just the half-angle identity $$\cos 2\theta=\frac{1-\tan^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}$$

and a bit of simple algebra.

Comment: Personally, I find this *much* more complicated than a straightforward application of energy conservation. It's always interesting to see what techniques different people find to be "simple."

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I worked out the algebra and pretty much I was complicating myself, but I have some doubts, why the angle that G and F form is the same the pendulum moves away from the vertical?